# Given the rank and frequency find the constant in Zipfs law

Tags: power-law, zipf

From a total of $N$ words i have the following dataset where the first column represents the ranks and the second the frequency. For example
$$\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 4300 \\
2 & 3100 \\
3 & 2500 \\
4 & 1900 \\
\vdots & \vdots
\end{array}
$$
I want to find the constant where satisfies $$cf_i =\frac{\text{const}}{i}$$ where $i$ is the rank and $cf_i$ the frequency.
I have plotted the loglog plot of the data and found the fitting line through regression but i cannot understand how to found $\text{const}$. Any ideas?

Comment: You have $\displaystyle cf_i = \frac{\text{const}} i.$ Dividing both sides by $c$ you get$\vphantom{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle\int}{\displaystyle\int}}$$$ f_i = \frac{\text{const}/c} i = \frac{\text{a different constant}} i, $$ so only _one_ constant is involved. In other words, your way of writing it makes it appear slightly more complicated than it is. $\qquad$